# .NET Maui: Borders popping-in on first click of a tabbed page on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, maui

I have a Tabbed Page with 4 Content Pages which are dynamically generated with C# code. When the tabbed page is loaded, we have logic which sets the TabbedPage.CurrentPage to the Content Page with index '1' or '2', and everything works as intended. However, when you click on the tab for the Content Page with index '0', the Border objects will pop in. In other words, they start small in the top left corner and then expand to full size with a little animation. This doesn't happen after the first time it is selected but it is bothering me so much. Android has no issues whatsoever.

I will also note that the 'Content' of the border (the text within the border) does not pop-in, it will be already in its final position when the user clicks on the tab, but the background of the border will pop-in.

The problem seems to be related to the fact that the CurrentPage is being changed in the code. When I programmatically change to the other tabs, they will all pop in.

```
TabbedPage.CurrentPage = TabbedPage.Children[1];
TabbedPage.CurrentPage = TabbedPage.Children[2];
TabbedPage.CurrentPage = TabbedPage.Children[3];
```

This causes all of the Content pages to pop in except for index '3' because that is the page we are starting on now.

Comment: 1.Please help create [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and add it to your post. 2.Please help create a screenshot of the issue.

Comment: Please show what it looks like and provide the relevant code, because it's quite unclear what the problem is.